# Ошибка cs0535 в WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, шаблоны-проектирования

Как исправить ошибку cs0535 в WinForms? Класс Car : ITransport. В интерфейсе есть метод. В Классе Car данный метод реализован, но появляется ошибка cs0535.
Листинг Класса Car

```
 class Car : ITransport
{
    public double Takings(double a)
    {
        return a * a;
    }

    
}
```

Листинг интерфейса ITransport

```
interface ITransport
{
    double Takings();
           
        
}
```

}

Comment: Метод в интерфейсе и Ваша реализация в классе отличаеются, Вам так не кажется? Для реализации интерфейса имя, тип возвращаемого значения и параметры (сумма, порядок и тип) должны совпадать.

Comment: не поняла что вы хотели сказать

Comment: Интерфейсы - это скажем так, контракт, по которому вы должны строго следовать. Вот у вас в интерфейсе `double Takings()` - некий метод с названием `Takings`, который возвращает `double` и **не имеет** параметров. Теперь смотрим реализацию в классе  `public double Takings(double a)` - **публичный** метод `Takings`, который возвращает `double` и **требует параметры** `double a`. Жирным я выделил то, что отличается. Модификаторы доступа вы можете без проблем менять, это интерфейс позволит, а вот параметры, где они прописаны в интерфейсе? Вы нарушели контракт.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface ITransport
{
    double Takings(double a);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]